# Is a URL rewrite supposed to clean up a dirty link?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a URL rewrite that works perfectly. If someone navigates to `www.mypage.com/stuff`, it shows them the page content with an actual URL of `www.mypage.com/category.php?category=stuff`.

The problem is, my dynamic page links everything with dirty links generated from a MySQL database. So when someone goes to `www.mypage.com`, they can click on any number of links, and all of them included php variables. They don't get cleaned up by the rewite rule, since it only works the other way, right? What does everyone do to clean them up for people navigating the page with dynamic variable links?

I am NOT a veteran PHP coder. Please take the time to make sure your response is worded for a novice, I will greatly appreciate it.

Server is running Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They don't get cleaned up by the rewite rule, since it only works the other way, right?

Right. They only redirect `/stuff` to `/category.php?category=stuff`. Not the only way.

> What does everyone do to clean them up for people navigating the page with dynamic variable links?

In short, clean up the links to use the *pretty* URLs.

In more detail, you noted the links are generated via MySQL. Update the code to output the *pretty* links. Searching your codebase for `category.php?category=` would likely get you started.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I needed to do URL rewrites after all, although not for the reasons I originally thought! Once I'm done with them I'll fix my code and get this mess looking legit. Thanks for clearing that up.